# Display Images with bgl

Tags: python, image, opengl

I'm trying to display an image external to blender in the 3d view with python and bgl. Is it possible not to load an image in data.images and display it?

The following code display an image from the data.images :

```
import bpy
import bgl


def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    img = bpy.data.images[0]

    x1 = 50
    y1 = 50
    x2 = bpy.context.area.regions[4].width-50
    y2 = bpy.context.area.regions[4].height-50

    img.gl_load(bgl.GL_NEAREST, bgl.GL_NEAREST)
    bgl.glBindTexture(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, img.bindcode[0])
    bgl.glTexParameteri(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, bgl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, bgl.GL_NEAREST)

    bgl.glTexParameteri(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, bgl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, bgl.GL_NEAREST)
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)

    bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_QUADS)
    bgl.glTexCoord2f(0,0)
    bgl.glVertex2f(x1,y1)
    bgl.glTexCoord2f(0,1)
    bgl.glVertex2f(x1,y2)
    bgl.glTexCoord2f(1,1)
    bgl.glVertex2f(x2,y2)
    bgl.glTexCoord2f(1,0)
    bgl.glVertex2f(x2,y1)
    bgl.glEnd()
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D)


class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal View3D Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')


            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```